# What does the following IPMI error mean: Processor /CATERR (#0x68)

Tags: ipmi

I have seen this error on a system with a Nehalem server motherboard.  When it happens, the system freezes and will eventually reboot.

The full error is:

Processor /CATERR (#0x68)       Informational event: CATERR reports it has been deasserted.     BMC - LUN #0 (Channel #00h)

If you don't know anything about this exact error, I would still like to understand exactly what a "CATERR" is.

I should mention that the server is running a custom linux kernel based off 2.6.18.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an “MCERR class” error occurs,CATERR# is asserted for 16 BCLKs.

If an “IERR class” error occurs,CATERR# remains asserted until warm or cold reset.

FYR:http://www.intel.in/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/platform-level-error-strategies-paper.pdf

Answer (score 3):

A processor CATERR is a CATastrophic ERRor asserted by the processor.  As for the error itself, more info would help.